# Using "snakemake --config" to pass a list of strings

Tags: yaml, config, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm having issues trying to pass a list of two strings to my Snakemake workflow via the `--config` parameter.

My config.yaml contains a list variable with two strings.

illumina_input: ["sample1/forward.fastq", "sample1/reverse.fastq"]

This works properly when I use Snakemake with changing the values in this YAML file.

Now I would like to run a batch of multiple Snakemake runs using a shell script, each providing different Illumina paired-end reads to use. I'm currently testing on one rule only.

Example:

```
snakemake --config \
outdir=testoutputfolder/ \
illumina_input=["sample1/forward.fastq","sample1/reverse.fastq"] -r short_read_trimming

snakemake --config \
outdir=testoutputfolder/ \
illumina_input=["sample2/forward.fastq","sample2/reverse.fastq"] -r short_read_trimming
```

Part of Snakefile

```py
rule all:
    input:
        config["outdir"] + "reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina1_trimmed_paired.fq", config["outdir"] + "reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina2_trimmed_paired.fq"

rule short_read_trimming:
    input:
        config["illumina_input"]
    output:
        [config["outdir"] + "reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina1_trimmed_paired.fq",
        config["outdir"] + "reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina2_trimmed_paired.fq"]
    shell:
        "java -jar {config[trimmomatic_loc]} PE {input[0]} {input[1]} \
        {config[outdir]}reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina1_trimmed_paired.fq {config[outdir]}reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina1_trimmed_unpaired.fq \
        {config[outdir]}reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina2_trimmed_paired.fq {config[outdir]}reference-data-shortreads/trimmed/illumina2_trimmed_unpaired.fq \
        {config[trimmomatic_params]}"
```

When I try to run this code I receive the following error

```
Invalid config definition: Config entries have to be defined as name=value pairs.
```

I can't seem to figure out how to provide lists to the Snakemake configuration via the command line. I've tried to remove the brackets, comma's and replace them with whitespace but nothing seems to work.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: A very simple example for how to pass a list of strings through `--config files=['a.txt','b.txt']` can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68238265/how-to-pass-a-list-or-dictionary-using-snakemakes-command-line-config-option/68238266#68238266

Comment: A good reference for config handling in general is available here: https://github.com/tsibley/blab-standup/blob/master/2021-11-04.md#specifying-config

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just remove the space in between the items in the list!

```
snakemake --config \
outdir=testoutputfolder/ \
illumina_input=["sample2/forward.fastq","sample2/reverse.fastq"]
```

Comment: I've already tried that but I keep receiving the following error messages in all rules that need the list variable. `MissingInputException in line 29 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule quality_control_raw_shortreads:
[Serge/reference-data-shortreads/Candidatus-carsonella-ruddii/illumina1.fq,Serge/reference-data-shortreads/Candidatus-carsonella-ruddii/illumina2.fq]`

Comment: Btw I did specify the full absolute path to the two files. ;)

Comment: @SergeW that error message indicates that snakemake accepts the illumina_input in the config, and it crashes somewhere else. I have nowhere near enough info to understand where that happens.

Comment: I can understand. I have added some new information about the issue. Maybe I should just provide the two strings as separate variables to get around the issue?