# How to pass a list or dictionary using Snakemake's command line config option

Tags: snakemake

I want to pass a list of filenames to produce through my Snakemake workflow by using the `--config` CLI option. What's the syntax I need for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specify the list or dict in YAML (~Python) syntax on the command line:

```bash
snakemake -c1 --config 'foo={"a":"a.txt", "b":"b.txt"}' 'bar=["file1.txt","file2.csv"]'
```

You can then access this list in a sample Snakemake rule as follows:

```yaml
rule all:
    input:
        baz=config["foo"]["a"],
        qux=config["foo"]["b"],
        quux=config["bar"],
```

As usual, the name before the `=` will be how you access the data after the `=` through the `config` variable. Multiple config items can be passed through space separation as shown above.

Here is the full parsing order of the `--config` CLI option (as of November '21):

> `--config key=value [key=value […]]` sets top-level keys to the given
> value, which is parsed, in order, as either: `int(value)`, `float(value)`,
> literal `True` or `False` (a `bool`), a YAML-encoded value, or finally
> `str(value)`.  Only the last occurrence of the option is used if it is
> given more than once.
> https://github.com/tsibley/blab-standup/blob/master/2021-11-04.md#specifying-config

The full post is a good reference of how Snakemake config handling works (the documentation is a bit lacking at times).